# Android ArcGIS API, how to loop into every Feature in Geodatabase

Tags: file-geodatabase, android, feature-layer, arcgis-android

I have an offline geodatabase in android ArcGIS which I have downloaded through gdbAsyncTask.

how do I loop into every feature in that geodatabase?

for example I could have collect all the IDs from the geodatabase and then loop into each in a for loop but this is not possible.

```
new FeatureLayer(localGdb.getGeodatabaseFeatureTableByLayerId(id)).getFeatureIDs(x,y,tolerance);
```

getFeatureIDs method does not work since I guess I have to also add the layer in my map. But I want to do that without having to add it to my map. Since I need to get the geometries only.

After the point: `localGdb.getGeodatabaseFeatureTableByLayerId(id)`, how do I guery for all the features? or query for all the feature IDs, so then I can reach every feaure?

Answer (score 1):

The oid of the features in the feature layer generally match the 'rowid' so can be used incrementally.

```
Long lenLayer = gvOC.geodatabaseFeatureTable.getNumberOfFeatures();
Long featureid;
Geometry g;
for (long i = 1; i <= lenLayer;  i++) { 
        Feature selectedFeature = gvOC.featureLayer.getFeature(i);
        featureid = selectedFeature.getId();
        g = selectedFeature.getGeometry();
}
```